# Difference between property as function and method

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm wondering what the difference between `foo` and `bar` is in the following interface:

```
interface Test
{
    foo( value: number): string;
    bar: ( value: number ) => string;
}


let x: Test = {
    foo: ( i ) => "",
    bar: ( i ) => "",
};
```

I's obvious that the first one is a method whereas the second is a property but is this otherwise semantically identical?

EDIT:

It doesn't seem to be completely equivalent. At least for the constructor method `now` only the first syntax seems to be valid:

```
class Test
{
}

interface TestConstructor
{
    new(): Test;
}

const activator = function( type: TestConstructor )
{
    return new type(); // fine
}

interface TestConstructor2
{
    new: () => Test;
}

const activator2 = function( type: TestConstructor2 )
{
    return new type(); // Error: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both equivalent. The first (`foo( value: number): string;`) is only syntactic sugar for the second (`foo: ( value: number ) => string;`). This is useful in case you want to define a high-level function as such:

`function test(myFunction: (value: number) => string)`

Comment: But can you explain the differences when it comes to the ```new```keyword (see the EDIT part in the question above)?